# Juego con caracteres python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un código que consiste en:

> Escribir un programa que comience leyendo en un vector una lista de palabras (máximo 25) y permita simular el siguiente juego:

- El ordenador selecciona aleatoriamente una palabra de la lista.
- A continuación el usuario intentará adivinar dicha palabra, letra a letra, permitiéndose un máximo de ocho fallos.
- Cada jugada o intento de adivinar una letra comenzará con un sorteo del valor de la jugada (número aleatorio de puntos entre 1000 y 10000) así como la presentación al usuario de la situación actual del juego (letras y posiciones adivinadas, total de puntos, total de fallos).
- Si la letra introducida por el usuario en una jugada se encuentra una o más veces en la palabra que se intenta adivinar, el total de puntos se incrementa en el valor de la jugada multiplicado por el número de veces que aparece la letra adivinada.

Como recorren el vector de las letras que van siendo encontradas junto con las posiciones?

```
import random
def valor(Valorjugada):
    Valorjugada = random.randint(1000,10000)
    return Valorjugada
  

Fallos = 0
Encontradas=0
Valorjugada = 0
Totalpuntos = 0
VectorEncontradas = []


Palabras = ["Auto", "Camion", "Argentina", "Teclado", "Living", "Cocina", "Brasil", "Lampara", "Pared", "Cortina", "Bicicleta", "Mueble", "Mesa", "Estadio", "Ventana" ]
Palabraseleccionada = random.choice(Palabras).lower()
VectorLetras = list(Palabraseleccionada) #lo mismo y mas eficiente
    
print(VectorLetras)


print("Debe adivinar la palabra")
while Encontradas < len(VectorLetras) and Fallos < 8: #mientras que tengas menos de 8 fallos o que hallas encontrado menos letras de las que hay en la palabra
    Letra = input("Introduce una letra :")
    if Letra in VectorLetras: #encuentra la letra en el vector
        print("Letra Encontrada")
        Encontradas += 1
        Valorjugada = valor(Valorjugada)
        VectorEncontradas.append(Encontradas)
        print(VectorEncontradas)
        
        print("El valor del jugada fue de: " + str(Valorjugada))
        Totalpuntos+=Valorjugada
        print("La puntuacion total es: " + str(Totalpuntos))
    else: #si no
        print("Fallaste")
        Fallos += 1
        print("Fallo numero: " + str(Fallos))
    if Fallos == 8:
        print("Cantidad de fallos excedida")
```

Answer (score 1):

De hecho te estas complicando mucho.

Estas iterando sobre el vector de caracteres cada vez que quieres comprobar si hay una letra en el vector, cuando podrías usar simplemente el comando `in`.

He remodelado tu código un poco:

```
import random

Fallos = 0
Encontradas=0

Palabras = ["Auto", "Camion", "Argentina", "Teclado", "Living", "Cocina", "Brasil", "Lampara", "Pared", "Cortina", "Bicicleta", "Mueble", "Mesa", "Estadio", "Ventana" ]
Palabraseleccionada = random.choice(Palabras)
VectorLetras = list(Palabraseleccionada) #lo mismo y mas eficiente
    
print(VectorLetras)


print("Debe adivinar la palabra")
while Encontradas < len(VectorLetras) and Fallos < 8: #mientras que tengas menos de 8 fallos o que hallas encontrado menos letras de las que hay en la palabra
    Letra = input("Introduce una letra :")
    if Letra in VectorLetras: #encuentra la letra en el vector
        print("Letra Encontrada")
        Encontradas += 1
    else: #si no
        print("Fallaste")
        Fallos += 1
```

Espero que esto te funcione. Cumple que:

- mientras no hallas adivinado todas las letras, no salga del bucle
- mientras no falles 8, no salga de el bucle
- cuando las aciertas todas, sale del bucle
- cuando fallas 8, también sale de el bucle

Comment: se me olvido lo de el puntaje de las jugadas xd